# Color en una palabra o mensaje

Tags: mysql, servlets, style

Buenos días amigos de Stackoverflow, una pregunta rapidísimo, he estado intentando encontrar la manera de como hacer que mi mensaje "RECHAZADO" se marque en rojo y si es posible el `background: yellow` a través de un `div`, por si se han dado cuenta he estado programando en servlet y estoy programando una base de datos MySQL, entonces uno de los resultados `<%=rs.getString(numero)%>` va a generar dos valores como "APROBADO" o "RECHAZADO" y lo que me interesa es poder marcar en este caso el del mensaje de rechazo en colores rojizos y estuve tratando de buscarle por `type/javascript` o por `style` a través de un método no sé un `if` y que de un `value` si es "RECHAZADO" lo puedas colorear con cierta tinta hexadecimal, la verdad es que no, no he podido encontrar la manera, no sé si sea una manera complicada y no sé si en realidad conozcan algún método que se le parezca, ¿no? Ya me topé con métodos fijos los comunes donde les pones color, con mensajes de `span`, hay una donde escribes en un input y te cambia el color pero la verdad es que no le entendí muy bien que digamos, se los agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar con ese detalle, por mi parte que pasen buen día y hasta entonces

Comment: Buen día,   quizás te pueda ayudar un poco esto: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/  Con un if else puedes indicar que se muestre según el valor que llegue.

Comment: mensaje "RECHAZADO" se marque en rojo y si es posible el background: yellow a través de un div, por si se han dado cuenta he estado programando en servlet y estoy programando una base de datos MySQL, entonces uno de los resultados <%=rs.getString(numero)%> va a generar dos valores como "APROBADO" o "RECHAZADO"